# Erase psql database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have psql installed in my Ubuntu system. There is a database named **tmpdb** in it. I want to delete it but get an error message:

> must be owner of database tmpdb".

I open psql with

```
  $psql postgres
  psql (9.5.6)
  Type "help" for help.

  postgres=>DROP DATABASE tmpdb;
  ERROR:  must be owner of database tmpdb
  postgres=>
```

How can I see owner, change it, so I can delete the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do any of that if you want to delete it the simple way is to use `dropdb` as a database super-user. Assuming that `postgres` is still a database super-user.

```
sudo -u postgres dropdb tmpdb;
```

See `man dropdb` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To see the owner of a database, the easiest way is to use the `\l` command (or `\l+` for some extra nerdy details) in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).
The owner can then be changed with

```
ALTER DATABASE tmpdb OWNER TO yournewowner;
```

In case you did not remember this exact syntax, you could have gotten some help with:

```
\h ALTER DATABASE
```

After this, you could delete your database with the `DROP DATABASE` command or with the [dropdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-dropdb.html) executable.